# Windows 8 Wifi Issue

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I'm using Windows 8.1 (didn't have Windows 8) and I'm experiencing a very frustrating issue.

Whenever I put the computer into standby (the majority of the time I use it), when it wakes back up, the wifi connection is limited. The **only** way that I can then get the wifi connection to work is to uninstall the network device through device manager, scan for changes, then enter the network password again.

Apart from being a hassle, every time I do this, I lose my configured settings for the connection - I use a DNS proxy so I have to reconfigure all my IP's etc.

I have scanned across the internet, but I'm completely stumped. I've tried all the usual things I can think of (e.g updating drivers, disabling power management for the network adapter), but nothing works.

This is a HP CQ57 and the adapter is a Realtek RTL8188CE adaptor.

Any help to avoid me ripping my hair out would be appreciated!

Comment: disable the powersaving (device manager) for the Wifi device.

Comment: Did you tried with disabling and enabling the device instead of uninstalling?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried both of those - disable/enable is my usual solution to wifi problems, but the connection is still limited. It has to be fully uninstalled and reinstalled. Power management settings in device manager don't seem to make a difference (or aren't taking effect)

Answer (score 0):

What driver do you have installed for your wifi? Latest one is v1086.48.0809.2011 available [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=272&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

A couple of other quick tests are:

1. To uninstall the drivers and then re-install them.
2. Right click on wifi connection (in desktop mode) and "Troubleshoot problems" to see if this fixes it or not (albeit temporarily)